# Automatic dishwasher opener

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, stepper-motor

I have a [Beko DFS28021X](https://www.beko.com/hu-hu/term%C3%A9kek/szabadon%C3%A1ll%C3%B3-mosogat%C3%B3g%C3%A9pek/szabadon%C3%A1ll%C3%B3-mosogat%C3%B3g%C3%A9p-10-ter%C3%ADt%C3%A9k-keskeny-dfs28021x) dishwasher. Unfortunately, it cannot open its door when the washing is done. I thought that this could be fixed using a stepper motor and a phototransistor (to detect the "program finished" light), controlled by an Arduino.
My problem is I don't have any experience in engineering, so I don't know what would be the best way to design the opener part. I have some experience with Arduino programming, but I lack the knowledge on both electrical and mechanical engineering.
I see two options for this project:

1. There's a small gap on the sides of the door, so maybe I could fit something there to push the door away from the body. The asymmetrically applied force might cause some damage, so optionally this should be done on both sides simultaneously.
2. I could use the handle of the door, but here I don't know what would be a proper way to attach the mechanical parts to both the door and the main body.

The dishwasher doesn't have a locking mechanism (I can open it even when the dishwasher is still running). This is good, because I won't destroy anything by opening while it is still locked. On the other hand, if the system wrongly detects that the program is done, I might flood my kitchen.

I have an access to a 3D printer, and also I have some tools to work with wood, I don't know which one would be better.

Did anyone do anything similar? Can anyone provide me some guidance on this? (Of course if you think it's unfeasible, it is a useful feedback as well.)

Comment: Aim for a good-enough design, not the best design. If it's supposed to open and does not, try fixing the existing mechanism.

Comment: `cannot open its door when the washing is done` ... why not open it later?

Comment: @Abel unfortunately it has no option for this by design

Comment: @jsotola I would mainly use it when we are going on a long trip. We would start the dish washer when we're leaving, and it would open automatically when it's done. Currently the problem is that if we would leave it there e.g. for a week, the dishes wouldn't dry, and the dish washer would smell very bad afterwards (not to mention fungi growing in the system).